# Is it possible to create a strictly typed React HOC in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

As context, I'm attempting to create a higher order component to wrap React Native components and add some functionality based on a ref to the component.

Short, untyped example:

```js
export function withHelper(WrappedEl) {
  return ({
    layoutParam,
    onChangeLayout,
    ...wrappedElProps
  }) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const onLayout = useCallback(() => {
      ref.current?.measure((_x, _y, width, height, px, py) => {
        onChangeLayout({
          layout: {
            width,
            height,
            y: py,
            x: px,
          },
          layoutParam,
        });
      });
    }, [
      onChangeLayout,
      layoutParam,
    ]);

    return <WrappedEl {...wrappedElProps} ref={ref} onLayout={onLayout} />;
  };
}
```

`measure` is a React Native element that gives me some information I need about the element for rendering other things. It's from the interface `NativeMethods`.

What I'd like to get strictly typed here:

- The HOC can only be used on elements that have the `measure` method.
- The resulting component is appropriately typed with all the original component's props as well as the two added props (`layoutParam` and `onChangeLayout`).

This is how far I got:

```js
interface WithHelperProps {
  layoutParam: string;
  onChangeLayout: (props: {layout: Layout, payoutParam: string}) => void;
}

export function withHelper<
  P extends object,
  V extends React.ComponentClass<P> & Constructor<NativeMethods>,
>(El: V): React.FC<P & WithHelperProps> {
  return ({
    layoutParam,
    onChangeLayout,
    ...props
  }) => {
    const ref = useRef<InstanceType<V>>(null);
    const onLayout = useCallback(() => {
      ref.current?.measure((_x, _y, width, height, px, py) => {
        onChangeLayout({
          layout: {
            width,
            height,
            y: py,
            x: px,
          },
          layoutParam,
        });
      });
    }, [
      onChangeLayout,
      layoutParam,
    ]);

    const passthroughProps: Omit<
      PropsWithChildren<P & WithHelperProps>,
      keyof WithHelperProps
    > = props;

    return <El {...passthroughProps} ref={ref} onLayout={onLayout} />;
  };
}
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
Type 'Omit<PropsWithChildren<P & WithHelperProps>, keyof WithHelperProps> & { ref: RefObject<InstanceType<V>>; onLayout: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<P, any, any> & NativeMethods> & LibraryManagedAttributes<...>'.
  Type 'Omit<PropsWithChildren<P & WithHelperProps>, keyof WithHelperProps> & { ref: RefObject<InstanceType<V>>; onLayout: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<V, Readonly<P>>'.
```

I've been playing with it for a while and searching around, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

---

I made a [minimal reproduction in Replit](https://replit.com/@TotempaaltJ/DarkorangeSnivelingSorting#src/App.tsx).

Comment: This is a pretty well-put-together brain teaser. damn

Comment: Haha thanks @Y.Gherbi... I ended up going a non-HOC route to avoid this problem altogether, but I'd still love a solution.

Comment: I tried helping you for at least an hour but I ended up with more errors than I began with, avoiding HOC might not be a bad thing after all haha

Answer (score 4):

I think you just forgot to `forwardRef` your component's `ref`, which is needed since the HOC will be wrapping another component. Here's a simplified version (I'll update to your specific use case in a moment) for the sake of demonstration.

```
interface Layout {
  height: number
  width: number
  x: number
  y: number
}

interface WithHelperProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode
  layoutParam: string
  onChangeLayout: (props: { layout: Layout, layoutParam: string }) => void
}

const withHelper = <T, P = {}>(
  Render: React.ComponentType<P & { ref?: React.Ref<T> }>,
) => {
  const HOC = React.forwardRef<T, P & WithHelperProps>(
    ({ children, ...props }, ref) => {
      return (
        <Render {...(props as P)} ref={ref}>
          {children}
        </Render>
      )
    },
  )
  return HOC
}
```

Hope that helps! Cheers

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this does not ensure one important thing: that the passed component actually has the `measure` method on its ref. How should that be resolved?

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to narrow down using `<T extends { measure: ... }, P ... >`